# Get substring from file using "sed"

Tags: bash, sed, substring

Can anyone help me to get substring using [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) program?

I have a file with this line:

```
....
define("BASE", "empty"); # there can be any string (not only "empty").
....
```

And I need to get "empty" as string variable to my bash script.

At this moment I have:

```
sed -n '/define(\"BASE\"/p' path/to/file.ext
# returns this line:
# define("BASE", "empty");
# but I need 'empty'
```

**UPD:** Thanks to [@Jaypal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/970195/jaypal)

For now I have bash script:

```
DBNAME=`sed -n '/define(\"BASE\"/p' path/to/file.ext`
echo $DBNAME | sed -r 's/.*"([a-zA-Z]+)".*/\1/'
```

It work OK, but if there any way to make the same manipulation with one line of code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use is

```
sed -n 's/.*\".*\", \"\(.*\)\".*/\1/p' yourFile.txt
```

which means something (`.*`) followed by something in quotes (`\".*\"`), then a comma and a blank space (`,`), and then again something within quotes (`\"\(.*\)\"`).

The brackets define the part that you later can reuse, i.e. the string within the second quotes. used it with `\1`.

I put `-n` front in order to answer the updated question, to get online the line that was manipulated.

Comment: @Jeypal: Sorry, can't answer to yours. You forgot to take care for the first quotes. As far as I can see you're code would find the first string, if `"empty"` is not next to the bracket you put into your search.

Answer (score 3):

This should help -

```
sed -r 's/.*"([a-zA-Z]+)"\);/\1/' path/to/file.ext
```

If you are ok with using `awk` then you can try the following -

```
awk -F\" '/define\(/{print $(NF-1)}' path/to/file.ext
```

#### Update:

```
DBNAME=$(sed -r '/define\(\"BASE\"/s/.*"([a-zA-Z]+)"\);/\1/' path/to/file.ext)
```

Comment: Sorry for not clean question, but I mean get the value in this define (there can be any string not only "empty").

Comment: Updated the answer. DBNAME variable will now have the string you wanted. :)

Comment: The updated regexp returns 'sed: -e ... Unmatched ( or \(' I'm preaty new in bash can you help me with this error.

Comment: Sorry Arthur, my bad. Forgot to escape the `(`. Try with the new one please.

Answer (score 1):

```
 sed -nr '/^define.*"(.*)".*$/{s//\1/;p}' path/to/file.ext
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I like @ezdazuzena answer a bit more. He give more descriptions and actually it worked on the time when I needed it.

Answer (score 0):

if your file doesn't change over time (i.e. **the line numbers will always be the same**) you can take the line, and use delimiters to take your part out:

```
`sed -n 'Xp' your.file  | cut -d ' ' -f 2 |cut -d "\"" -f 2`
```

assuming X is the line number of your required line